# How did the value of Object Array in javascript be operated?

Tags: javascript

I feel puzzled when I rethink of these two functions:

The first one goes like this:

> `var test = [1,2,3];`
>   `var ele = test[0];`
>   `ele= 2;`
>   `alert(test[0])`;

The result is 1. I think this is obvious. But when I meet this:

> `var test = [{id:1},{},{}];`
>   `var ele = test[0];`
>   `ele.id = 2;`
>   `alert(test[0].id);`

The result turns to be 2
So could anyone tell me that how the javascript work when it happens like this in the object array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, objects are assigned by reference, rather than copied in memory. So if you assign an existing object to a different variable, both will point to the same object in memory. Modifications to either will therefore be reflected in both.

```
var a = {id: 1, name: "bob"};
var b = a;
console.log(b.name); // bob
b.name = "bill";
console.log(a.name); // bill
```

So in your example, executing `ele.id = 2;` operates on the memory location holding the object at `test[0]`. The change to the `id` property of that object is reflected in both variables referencing it (`test[0], ele`)

Note that if you had assigned the entire array `test` to `ele`, modifying one of the array members would have been reflected in both `test, ele` since Arrays are objects in Javascript:

```
var test = [1,2,3];
// Assign array test to ele
var ele = test;
// Modify one member
ele[0] = 2;
alert(test[0]); // 2
```